# Vue load component _completely_ dynamic

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js

I think this is a very unusual use case, and I'm not talking about dynamically requiring components with webpack.

I want to be able to deploy "Apps" as Vue components on a completely different backend, so that the backend can return full `.vue` files over an API. The structure of the backend is irrelevant.
So I need a way in my Vue application to achieve the following:

- User clicks on an "app" name in the frontend Vue application
- "app" name is async-requested at the backend
- backend returns a `.vue` SFC file, with HTML, JS and CSS in it
- frontend compiles the file to a Vue component with template and functionality
- frontend inserts the component in the view, and the component can interact with the rest of the application (Vuex store etc.)

I found [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template) which seems to be the solution for templates. But this doesn't include the JS part, does it?

**Additional:**
I think I'm trying something like [VueJS Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components), but the request URL has to be set dynamically.

Comment: The problem that I see here is that having the front-end interpret the raw `.vue` file means the front end has to interpret any template syntax that that Vue file has including less, scss, pug, and whatever else templating languages your Vue file might utilize.  I think you still want the backend interpreting the file, but for the front-end to consume plain JSON definition of the Vue component.  That's what Webpack is doing behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: I am free to extend the backend as I want, so compiling pug, sass etc. in the backend would be possible. But how would a plain JSON definition of a Vue component look like, especially the methods and computedProps?

Answer (score 4):

Markus Oberlehner [has an article](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/) that I think addresses your problem. The solution is through a externalComponent(url) function that takes the place of an import() function. I've copied Markus' function here for easy reference:

```js
// src/utils/external-component.js
export default async function externalComponent(url) {
  const name = url.split('/').reverse()[0].match(/^(.*?)\.umd/)[1];

  if (window[name]) return window[name];

  window[name] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve(window[name]);
    });
    script.addEventListener('error', () => {
      reject(new Error(`Error loading ${url}`));
    });
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });

  return window[name];
}
```

According to the article, you can use the externalComponent() helper function to load external components pretty much the same way as we are used to with import().

Answer (score 1):

You might get by using [http-vue-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader). It's not generally recommended for production, but your use case might make it appropriate. Obviously there will be some limitations (e.g. `import`ing other modules)

Comment: How do I register a component at runtime with http-vue-loader? All examples on the GitHub page also define the component beforehand in the `new Vue()` constructor.

Comment: Still no idea.. I included `Vue.component("Test", httpVueLoader("http://localhost/Test.vue"))`, but nothing is happening. No XHR call and nothing in the console. Am I doing something wrong regarding TypeScript? I imported `Vue from "vue"` and httpVueLoader with `require("../node_modules/..:")`.